# Power BI Measure - Checkbook balance column

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns, calculation

Objective:
Looking to generate a column measure (DYNAMIC BALANCE) which reads the *first* row of BALANCE, and calculate the balance from subsequent rows using AMOUNT column.

Problems encountered:

1. Measure should ignore the AMOUNT on the first row and only capture the BALANCE into a variable.
2. My first row formula grabs both values for 1/1/2021 rather than only the top most row balance value.

| Date | Description | AMOUNT | BALANCE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2021 | Dog Food | -20.00 | 980.00 |
| 1/1/2021 | McDonalds | -30.00 | 950.00 |
| 1/5/2021 | Pay Day | 1000.00 | 1950.00 |
| 1/8/2021 | Dog Food | -20.00 | 1930.00 |
| 1/10/2021 | Medical | -1000.00 | 930.00 |
| 1/18/2021 | McDonalds | -30.00 | 900.00 |
| 1/21/2021 | Pay Day | 1000.00 | 1900.00 |
| 1/31/2021 | Dog Food | -50.00 | 1850.00 |
| 2/2/2021 | McDonalds | -40.00 | 1810.00 |

You are my hero!

Comment: Much More Complicated Semi-Similar idea with Solution 
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Checkbook-Type-of-Report/m-p/2172503/highlight/true#M797813

Comment: This looks promising.  Create an index column and reference using summarize to generate a virtual table. 
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5k4fD1YJrQ

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution.  Funny how the solution is so simple in DAX and in hindsight.  M-Code would have been more complicated.  DAX is dynamic to the filter which is necessary.

New Measure:

```
RunningTotal = FIRSTNONBLANK(bankdownload[Balance],0)+SUM(bankdownload[Amount])-FIRSTNONBLANK(bankdownload[Amount],0)
```